# How do you save a true or false state for listed elements in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can I make this display `<p>hi</p>` when `true`?  I don't want to do it for everything mapped by tickets.map.  I just want it to work for item clicked on.  I'm not how this is done in React.  Saving a state would effect everything mapped.  I tried to save the states in an array but React is too spastic and would flood the array with more items than were listed.

```
function App () {    
          const [chgState, setChgState] = useState({trueOrFalseState: []});
          const chgStateToggle = (i) => {
            setChgState(!chgState.trueOrFalseState[i]);
          }
        
          return (
            <div>
              {tickets.map((ticket) => {
                ticket.indexInChgState = getStateIndex();
                return <li key={ticket.id}>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary buttonSubCSS" onClick={() => chgStateToggle(chgState.trueOrFalseState[ticket.indexInChgState])} variant="primary">Chg</button>
                    {chgState.trueOrFalseState[ticket.indexInChgState] && <p>hi</p>}
                  </div>
                </li>
              })}
            </div>
          )
}
```

Comment: is trueOrFalseState an array of boolean?

Comment: I want just const [chgState] to be an array but I need to lookup what React wants in its states.  So I made chgState an object with trueOrFalseState an array in that object.  Which is declared on line 2.

Comment: @DrwooiPoipoi anything past your first question I didn't understand, the bits where you talk what you've tried should be in code because it's impossible to guess what you tried. Back to your question: if the condition before Logical AND `&&` is a Boolean then the `p` tag would show/hide based on that.

Comment: I'm re-writing it to have a state with an array that checks true or false.  Then I will post the changes.  Based on a deleted comment... not sure why it got deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an object instead of an array

```
const [chgState, setChgState] = useState({});

// chgState structure: {0: true, 1: false, 2: true}

const chgStateToggle = (i) => {
   // if element doesn't exist add then set it to true otherwise toggle it's existing value
   chgState[i] ? 
    setChgState({...chgState, [i]: !chgState[i] }): 
    setChgState({...chgState, [i]: true })
}
```

Then try

```
{chgState[idx] && <p>hi</p>}
```

Change your click handler

```
onClick={() => chgStateToggle(idx)}
```

And why you are not using the index provider by map

```
 {tickets.map((ticket, idx) => {
```

I created a working example for you here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-display-list-of-items-fkntzn?file=App.jsx

Comment: So I have an array that is being created and updated for each ticket.  chgState is an array with false for each element.  It is tracked by an index number on each ticket mapped.  Clicking the button changes the boolean to its opposite.  Console log shows everything is working... but its not displaying

<button onClick={() => chgStateToggle(ticket.ticketIndex)}>Chg</button>
            {chgState[ticket.ticketIndex] && <p>hi</p>}

chgState is reporting the correct value of true or false.  ticketIndex is checked to be the right index. 

Maybe useEffect(), [chgState] but I'm really not sure

Comment: I have a working example and it works, why you are not using the index provider by map?? there is no need for  ticket.indexInChgState = getStateIndex();

Comment: Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-display-list-of-items-fkntzn?file=App.jsx

Comment: even this code doesnt work, it always shows 'bye'.
<p>{chgState[ticket.ticketIndex] ? 'hi' : 'bye'}</p>
 It displays bye.  i even made a button to check if chgState[ticket.ticketIndex] was true or false

Comment: my bad i changed it, use  {chgState[idx] && <p>hi</p>}

Comment: That is crazy.  I still have no idea why your code causes React to update and mine did not.  Maybe because I was changing the entire array with setChgState([modified array]) or something was being weird.  Thanks for the live example!  I ended up using the code below to test it out.

    <p>{chgState[index] ? 'hi' : 'bye'}</p>

Comment: 99% the problem of your code is in  ticket.indexInChgState = getStateIndex()